# c# - sql print checked boxes

Tags: c#, sql, datagrid

```
string filter = string.Empty;
if (checkboxBalkon.Checked== true)
{
     filter = "Balkon LIKE '%" + checkboxBalkon.Checked + "%'"; //???
}
```

I have search form. The code above is supposed to print down all fields from table that has checkbox checked. I compare it, but i don't know how to print it? I need some bool? How to do it?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  For us to answer a question like this, we really need more details.  For example, what do you mean by "print it"?  Your question seems to infer things that we don't know.  Could you add some more information?  Thanks.

Comment: I have button Filter and datagrid with all data. When i click on Filter button it should show me(print, write..) in datagrid only data that has checked checkbox on field "Balkon"( not to show those where checkbox is not checked). It is search form, and it already works for text like if i search for some name.... but i don't know how to do with checkboxes..

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer you are looking for is something like this:

```
filter = "Balkon = " + checkboxBalkon.Checked;
```

Comment: Damn how dumb of me :p I was tring al sorts of like, true, =1...Thanks!

Comment: @cevudj21 - Glad I could help.  Sometime it just takes a second set of eyes.  If this is the answer you were looking for, I would recommend that you accept it as the answer.  That way it won't sit on the list of questions yet to be answered and people that come across this question in the future know what the answer was to your question.